# Accessing specialFolderPath("documents") on Android

Tags: android, directory-structure, livecode

I created a livecode application with sqlite database.

I found this [article](http://lessons.runrev.com/m/4069/l/30516-how-to-create-and-use-an-sqlite-database) from livecode website.

I found this script from that article.

```
 put specialFolderPath("documents") & "/runrevemails.sqlite" into tDatabasePath
```

That means the database file of the sqlite is stored at that folder. In windows, the "runrevemails.sqlite" file is stored in My Documents folder. But in android, I don't know where is that file stored. I was searching for that file but I can't find it.

Where is that file in android device?
What is the directory structure of the `specialFolderPath("documents")`?
How can I access it?

Comment: These likely refer to subfolders of the application's private storage.  See the android developer docs on storage.

Comment: Connect your phone to a computer. The memory card of the phone should appear on your desktop. Browse the phone's drive to find your documents. A file manager may also be able to display the files on Android, but it may not have write access.

Comment: I am still unable to find that file. I was looking at the Documents folder at the internal storage, nothing is there. @Mark

Comment: Can you give me a link to that topic? @ChrisStratton

Comment: Sounds like you haven't explored the developer site yet.  Do so.  As for Mark's comments, the contents of **internal** storage are not browsable by a connected computer as they are supposed to be private to the associated apps.  Its quite unlikely that a file manager would have read-only access - more likely it has read/write or most likely no access at all.